# Start service on start up

Tags: android, service

I`m having problems when trying to start a service on android start up, as soon as the phone starts my app gives an error and has to stop it. Here it is:

part of my manifest:

```
<service
    android:name=".EventsNotificationService"
    android:label="EventsNotificationService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action
            android:name="it.bloomp.service.EventsNotificationService" />
    </intent-filter>
/service>

<receiver
    android:name=".receiver.StartEventsNotificationService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:label="StartEventsNotificationService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action
            android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

my service:

```
package it.bloomp.service;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class EventsNotificationService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Service created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Service destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Service started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

my service starter:

```
package it.bloomp.service;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class StartEventsNotificationService extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("it.bloomp.service.EventsNotificationService");
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, this make the service start on start up, but how can I make it run all time?

**EDIT:**

The exceptions:

> 06-01 16:58:55.716: E/AndroidRuntime(483): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 06-01
>   16:58:55.716: E/AndroidRuntime(483): java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to instantiate receiver
>   it.bloomp.activity.receiver.StartEventsNotificationService:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   it.bloomp.activity.receiver.StartEventsNotificationService 06-01
>   16:58:55.716: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2100)
>   06-01 16:58:55.716: E/AndroidRuntime(483):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123) 06-01
>   16:58:55.716: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1197)
>   06-01 16:58:55.716: E/AndroidRuntime(483):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 06-01
>   16:58:55.716: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 06-01 16:58:55.716:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(483):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 06-01
>   16:58:55.716: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 06-01
>   16:58:55.716: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 06-01 16:58:55.716:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(483):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   06-01 16:58:55.716: E/AndroidRuntime(483):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 06-01
>   16:58:55.716: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 06-01 16:58:55.716:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(483): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   it.bloomp.activity.receiver.StartEventsNotificationService 06-01
>   16:58:55.716: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
>   06-01 16:58:55.716: E/AndroidRuntime(483):    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501) 06-01
>   16:58:55.716: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461) 06-01
>   16:58:55.716: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2095)
>   06-01 16:58:55.716: E/AndroidRuntime(483):    ... 10 more

EDIT2:

My manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="it.bloomp.activity"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="4"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <activity
            android:name=".EventsListActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".EventActivity"/>

        <service android:name=".EventsNotificationService" android:label="EventsNotificationService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="it.bloomp.service.EventsNotificationService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name=".StartEventsNotificationService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="StartEventsNotificationService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

My service:

```
package it.bloomp.service;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class EventsNotificationService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        System.out.println("Service created.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        System.out.println("Service destroyed.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onCreate();
        System.out.println("Service started.");
    }
}
```

My service starter:

```
package it.bloomp.service;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class StartEventsNotificationService extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("it.bloomp.service.EventsNotificationService");
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

My exceptions:

> 06-03 15:37:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(479): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 06-03
>   15:37:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(479): java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to instantiate receiver
>   it.bloomp.activity.StartEventsNotificationService:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   it.bloomp.activity.StartEventsNotificationService 06-03 15:37:36.142:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(479):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2100)
>   06-03 15:37:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(479):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123) 06-03
>   15:37:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1197)
>   06-03 15:37:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(479):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 06-03
>   15:37:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 06-03 15:37:36.142:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(479):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 06-03
>   15:37:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 06-03
>   15:37:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 06-03 15:37:36.142:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(479):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   06-03 15:37:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(479):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 06-03
>   15:37:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 06-03 15:37:36.142:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(479): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   it.bloomp.activity.StartEventsNotificationService 06-03 15:37:36.142:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(479):    at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
>   06-03 15:37:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(479):    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501) 06-03
>   15:37:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461) 06-03
>   15:37:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2095)
>   06-03 15:37:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(479):    ... 10 more

Comment: "how can I make it run all time?" -- users have the right to get rid of your service whenever they want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

android:name=".receiver.StartEventsNotificationService"

probably should be

android:name=".StartEventsNotificationService"

EDIT

try this as your intent:

Intent i = new Intent(context, EventNotificationService.class);

also, you should update the error you received. It can't be the same as what you have, given what you've shown from your manifest and service starter code. Try to read the errors yourself and follow where they point to, learning how to do that efficiently will save you tons of time on StackOverflow and will teach you a lot better than just asking others.

Comment: I doubt its the same error, considering the error says: E/AndroidRuntime(483): Caused by: **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: it.bloomp.activity.receiver.StartEventsNotificationService** 06-01 16:58:55.716:

Comment: Thanks, i got it, I was not using the a fully qualified class name on my manifest.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see the permission in the manifest file. You should add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Moreover, at first try to check if a service is started in the log. After that just make toast, maybe problems are there.

Comment: I`ve already added the permission, just forgot to post it. I check the log and found nothing =s